# combine flat array elements

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array from my database like this :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [titre] => Quality
        [type_de_contenu] => pdf


    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [titre] => Quality
        [type_de_contenu] => doc


    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [titre] => Video
        [type_de_contenu] => video

    )
```

From this array i want to get :

```
array(
    "Quality"=>array(
         array(
            "titre"=>"Quality and certifications",
            "type_de_contenu" => doc
         ),
          array(
            "titre"=>"Quality and certifications 2",
            "type_de_contenu" => pdf
         ),
    ),
    "video"=>array(
        "titre" => "video",
        "type_de_contenu" => "video"
     )
)
```

As you see i want to combine all array with same title value, in one array, i have any idea and all my attempts are not good.

Could you help me please?

Thank you guys

Comment: post code from some of your attempts. also, where do you get 'Quality and certifications' string?

Comment: Show us what you tried, maybe?

Comment: You need to add the code that fetches that.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
    $tmpArr = array();
    foreach($dbArr as $k => $v)
    {
        if (!isset($tmpArr[$v['titre']]))
            $tmpArr[$v['titre']] = array();

        $tmpArr[$v['titre']][] = $v;
    }
    var_dump($tmpArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to use: https://github.com/jakezatecky/array_group_by

```
print_r(array_group_by($source, 'titre'));
```

But a a simple foreach loop would do just fine.

```
<?php
$source = [
    [
        "titre" => "Quality",
        "type_de_contenu" => "pdf",

    ],
    [
        "titre" => "Quality",
        "type_de_contenu" => "doc",

    ],
    [
        "titre" => "Video",
        "type_de_contenu" => "video",
    ],
];

$target = [];
foreach($source as $sub){
    $target[$sub['titre']][] = $sub;
}

print_r($target);

// will result in:
Array
(
    [Quality] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [titre] => Quality
                    [type_de_contenu] => pdf
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [titre] => Quality
                    [type_de_contenu] => doc
                )

        )

    [Video] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [titre] => Video
                    [type_de_contenu] => video
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: where is Quality with pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

please try with this

```
$array = array(
array(
    'titre'=>"Quality",
    'type_de_contenu'=>"pdf"
),
array(
    'titre'=>"Quality",
    'type_de_contenu'=>"doc"
),
array(
    'titre'=>"video",
    'type_de_contenu'=>"video"
   )
);
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($array);

$target_array = array();
foreach($array as $array1 ){     
    $target_array[$array1['titre']][] = array(
       'titre'=>"title text",
       'type_de_contenu'=>$array1['type_de_contenu']
    );      
 }

 print_r('<pre>');
 print_r($target_array);
```